# Positioning 2d percpective of a 3d world on the 3d world

Tags: javascript, canvas, webgl

So I have this method to draw all bunch of rectangles in a 3d world on a 2d world, I was able to position the 3d objects on the 2d canvas just fine, but now I want to place the 2d canvas in place instead of the rectangles, (that way ill be only drawing one big rectangle with an image instead every single rectangle again)

here's the method

```js
createBackground(objects) {
    const buffer = document.createElement("canvas").getContext("2d");

    const bufferRect = this.createEntity();
    const display = this.display;

    let {
      zAxis,
      canvas: {
        width,
        height,
      },
      currentCamera
    } = display;
    const cameraMatrix = currentCamera.matrix;

    zAxis--;
    const halfZ = zAxis / 2;
    let { coords: [x, y], area: [w, h] } = objects[objects.length - 1];

    const worldViewProjection = mat4.create();
    let [bX, bY, lX, lY] = [x+w, y+h, x-w, y-h]; //big x, little x

    for(let i = objects.length-1; i--;){
      const object = objects[i];
      const {coords: [_x, _y], area: [_w, _h]} = objects[i];

      if(_x > bX){
         bX = _x+_w;
      } else if(_x < lX) {
        lX = _x-_w;
      }
      if(_y > bY){
         bY = _y+_h;
      } else if(_y < lY) {
        lY = _y-_h;
      }

    }

    buffer.canvas.width = width;
    buffer.canvas.height = height;

    for (let i = objects.length; i--;) {
      const {
        coords: [_x, _y],
        area: [_w, _h]
      } = objects[i];
      mat4.multiply(worldViewProjection, this.display.currentCamera.matrix, objects[i].matrix);
      const points = [
        [-_w / 2, -_h / 2, 0],
        [ _w / 2,  _h / 2, 0],
      ].map(p => {
        const ndc = vec3.transformMat4([], p, worldViewProjection);
        return [
          (ndc[0] *  0.5 + 0.5) * width,
          (ndc[1] * -0.5 + 0.5) * height,
        ];
      });
      const ww = points[1][0] - points[0][0];
      const hh = points[1][1] - points[0][1];

      buffer.strokeStyle = 'red';
      buffer.strokeRect(...points[0], ww, hh);
    }

    bufferRect.move((bX+lX)/2, (bY+lY)/2);

    bufferRect.setSize(Math.abs(bX)+Math.abs(lX)-5, Math.abs(bY)+Math.abs(lY)-5);

    const texture = display.textureFromImage(buffer.canvas);

    bufferRect.attachImage(texture);

  }
```

the problem is right here where I try to position the rectangle in the middle and set its size to the distance between the far left rectangle and far right rectangle and some with top and bottom

```js
bufferRect.move((bX+lX)/2, (bY+lY)/2);

bufferRect.setSize(Math.abs(bX)+Math.abs(lX)-5, Math.abs(bY)+Math.abs(lY)-5);
```

and here's the full code

```js
const FRAGMENT_SHADER = ` precision highp float; varying highp vec2 vTextureCoord; varying lowp vec4 vColor; uniform sampler2D uSampler; uniform bool aUseText; void main(void) { if( aUseText ){ gl_FragColor = texture2D(uSampler, vTextureCoord); } else { gl_FragColor = vColor; } } `;
const VERTEX_SHADER = ` attribute vec4 aVertexPosition; attribute vec4 aVertexColor; attribute vec2 aTextureCoord; uniform mat4 uModelViewMatrix; uniform mat4 uProjectionMatrix; uniform mat3 uTextMatrix; uniform float uPointSize; varying lowp vec4 vColor; varying highp vec2 vTextureCoord; void main(void) { gl_PointSize = uPointSize; gl_Position = uProjectionMatrix * uModelViewMatrix * aVertexPosition; vColor = aVertexColor; vTextureCoord = (vec3(aTextureCoord, 1)*uTextMatrix).xy; } `;

function onResize(element, callback) {
  let elementHeight = element.height,
    elementWidth = element.width;

  setInterval(function() {
    if (element.height !== elementHeight || element.width !== elementWidth) {
      elementHeight = element.height;
      elementWidth = element.width;
      callback();
    }
  }, 16);
}


mat4.moveToVec3 = function(out, v) {
  out[12] = v[0];
  out[13] = v[1];
  out[14] = v[2];
};

class WebglEntity {
  constructor() {
    this.matrix = mat4.create();
    this.coords = vec3.create();
  }
  translate(newCoords) {
    const {
      matrix,
      coords
    } = this;
    mat4.translate(matrix, matrix, newCoords);
    vec3.copy(coords, [matrix[12], matrix[13], matrix[14]]);

    return this;
  }
  move(newCoords) {
    const {
      matrix,
      coords
    } = this;
    vec3.copy(coords, newCoords);
    mat4.moveToVec3(matrix, coords);

    return this;
  }
}

class Texture {

  constructor() {

    this.matrix = mat3.create();

    this.image = undefined;
    this.width = undefined;
    this.height = undefined;
    this.rotation = 0;
    this.y = 0;
    this.x = 0;

    let onload = function() {};

    Object.defineProperty(this, "onload", {
      get() {
        return onload;
      },

      set(value) {

        if (this.loaded) {
          value();
        } else {
          onload = value;
        }
      }
    });

    this.loaded = false;
  }

  setup(image, y, width, height, matrix, rotation) {

    this.image = image;
    this.y = y;
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
    this.rotation = 0;
    this.x = 0;

    if (matrix) {
      this.matrix = matrix;
      if (rotation) {
        this.rotation = rotation;

      }
    }

    this.loaded = true;
  }

  static from(texture) {

    const newTexture = new Texture();

    const {
      image,
      y,
      width,
      height,
      matrix,
      rotation
    } = texture;

    newTexture.setup(image, y, width, height, mat3.clone(matrix), rotation);

    return newTexture;
  }

  scale(w, h) {

    const matrix = this.matrix;

    mat3.scale(matrix, matrix, [w, h]);

  }

  rotate(rad) {

    const matrix = this.matrix;
    this.rotation = (this.rotation + rad) % (Math.PI * 2);

    mat3.rotate(matrix, matrix, rad);

  }
}
class Camera extends WebglEntity {
  constructor(fieldOfView, aspect, zNear, zFar) {
    super();

    this.projection = mat4.perspective(mat4.create(), fieldOfView, aspect, zNear, zFar);

  }
  lookAt(lookAt) {
    const {
      matrix,
      projection,
      coords
    } = this;
    mat4.lookAt(matrix, coords, lookAt, [0, 1, 0]);
    mat4.multiply(matrix, projection, matrix);
    return this;
  }
}
class Rect extends WebglEntity {

  constructor() {

    super();

    this.positionsBuffer = undefined;
    this.fragColorPos = undefined;
    this.strokeColorPos = undefined;
    this.strokePositionBuffer = undefined;
    this.vertexAttribInfo = undefined;
    this.vertextColorAttribInfo = undefined;
    this.vertexCount = undefined;
    this.textureInfo = undefined;
    this.strokeSize = 1;
    this.fillers = {
      fill: false,
      texture: false,
      stroke: false
    };


  }

  setup(matrix, positionsBuffer, strokePositionBuffer, vertexAttribInfo, vertextColorAttribInfo, vertexCount) {

    this.matrix = matrix;

    this.positionsBuffer = positionsBuffer;
    this.strokePositionBuffer = strokePositionBuffer;

    this.vertexAttribInfo = vertexAttribInfo;
    this.vertextColorAttribInfo = vertextColorAttribInfo;

    this.vertexCount = vertexCount;

    return this;
  }

  scale(scale) {

    const matrix = this.matrix;

    mat4.scale(matrix, matrix, scale);

    return this;

  }

  attachImage(newTexture) {
    this.fillers.texture = true;

    if (this.multiTextures) {
      this.textureInfo.push(newTexture);
      return;
    }

    this.textureInfo = newTexture;
    this.fillers.TRIANGLE_STRIP = true;

    return this;

  }

}

class Display {

  constructor(gl, programInfo, zAxis, texture) {
    this.gl = gl;
    this.programInfo = programInfo;

    this.canvas = gl.canvas;

    this.currentCamera = new Camera(45 * Math.PI / 180, gl.canvas.width / gl.canvas.height, 0.1, 100.0);

    this.currentCamera.translate([0, 0, zAxis]);

    this.currentCamera.lookAt([0, 0, 0]);

    this.zAxis = zAxis;
    this.drawZAxis = 0;

    texture.textAttribInfo = {
      numComponents: 2,
      type: gl.FLOAT,
      normalize: false,
      stride: 0,
      offset: 0
    };

    this.texture = texture;
    this.spriteSheets = [];

    const context = texture.context;
    const canvas = texture.canvas;

    this.images = {}; /*all the images with their src as their key*/

    onResize(texture.canvas, () => {

      const images = Object.values(this.images);
      for (let i = images.length; i--;) {

        const {
          image,
          y
        } = images[i];

        context.drawImage(image, 0, y);
      }

      const internalFormat = gl.RGBA;

      gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, internalFormat, internalFormat, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, canvas);

      gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_S, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
      gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_T, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
      gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
      gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);

    });

  }


  setSize(width, height) {

    const canvas = this.gl.canvas;

    canvas.width = width;
    canvas.height = height;

  }

  clear(color) {

    const gl = this.gl;

    gl.clearColor(0.1, 0.1, 0.3, 1);

    gl.clearDepth(1.0);
    gl.enable(gl.DEPTH_TEST);
    gl.depthFunc(gl.LEQUAL);

    gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);


  }
  fillRect(rect, color) {
    const {
      createStaticDrawBuffer,
      gl,
      parseColor
    } = this;

    rect.fillers.fill = true;

    if (color) {
      rect.fragColorPos = createStaticDrawBuffer(gl, [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1]);

    }
  }
  textureFromImage(image, texture) {

    const {
      images,
      texture: {
        canvas
      }
    } = this;

    texture = texture ? texture : new Texture();

    const {
      width,
      height
    } = image;

    const y = canvas.height;

    if (canvas.width < width) {

      canvas.width = width;

    }

    texture.setup(image, y, width, height, 0);

    canvas.height += height;

    images[images.length] = texture;

    return texture;

  }

  createRectPos(w, h) {

    const rect = [w / 2, h / 2, -w / 2, h / 2, w / 2, -h / 2, -w / 2, -h / 2];


    return {
      rect,
      stroke: undefined
    };
  }

  getRectInfo(x, y, rect, stroke) {

    return this.createSquareBuffer(rect, stroke, [x, y, this.drawZAxis]);
  }

  createStaticDrawBuffer(gl, data) {

    const buffer = gl.createBuffer();
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer);
    gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(data), gl.STATIC_DRAW);

    return buffer;
  }

  createSquareBuffer(positions, strokePosition, coords) {
    const {
      gl,
      createStaticDrawBuffer
    } = this;

    const positionsBuffer = createStaticDrawBuffer(gl, positions);
    const strokePositionBuffer = createStaticDrawBuffer(gl, strokePosition);
    const modelViewMatrix = mat4.create();

    mat4.translate(modelViewMatrix, modelViewMatrix, coords);

    return [modelViewMatrix, positionsBuffer, strokePositionBuffer, this.createAttribInfo(2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0), this.createAttribInfo(4, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0), positions.length / 2];
  }

  createAttribInfo(numComponents, type, normalize, stride, offset) {

    return {
      numComponents,
      type,
      normalize,
      stride,
      offset
    };
  }

  enableAttrib(buffer, attrib, gl, {
    numComponents,
    type,
    normalize,
    stride,
    offset
  }) {

    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer);
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(attrib, numComponents, type, normalize, stride, offset);
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray(attrib);

  }

  drawTexture(texture, gl, canvas, enableAttrib, createStaticDrawBuffer, textAttribInfo, vertexCount, textureCoord, textMatrix, useText) {

    const _width = canvas.width;
    const _height = canvas.height;

    const {
      x,
      y,
      width,
      height,
      matrix
    } = texture;

    const realX = x / _width;
    const realWidth = realX + width / _width;
    const realHeight = y / _height;
    const realY = (y + height) / _height;

    const fragTextPos = createStaticDrawBuffer(gl, [realWidth, realHeight, realX, realHeight, realWidth, realY, realX, realY, ]);

    gl.uniformMatrix3fv(textMatrix, false, matrix);
    enableAttrib(fragTextPos, textureCoord, gl, textAttribInfo);
    gl.uniform1f(useText, true);
    gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, vertexCount);

    gl.uniform1f(useText, false);
    gl.disableVertexAttribArray(textureCoord);
  }

  drawBuffer(buffer) {

    const {
      gl,
      drawTexture,
      enableAttrib,
      createStaticDrawBuffer,
      currentCamera,
      texture: {
        context,
        canvas,
        textAttribInfo
      },
      programInfo: {
        uniformLocations,
        program,
        attribLocations: {
          vertexPosition,
          vertexColor,
          textureCoord
        }
      }
    } = this;

    const cameraMatrix = currentCamera.matrix;

    const {
      positionsBuffer,
      fragColorPos,
      strokeColorPos,
      strokePositionBuffer,
      matrix,
      vertexAttribInfo,
      vertextColorAttribInfo,
      vertexCount,
      fragTextPos,
      fillers: {
        fill,
        stroke,
        texture
      },
      strokeSize,
      textureInfo,
      multiTextures
    } = buffer;

    gl.uniformMatrix4fv(uniformLocations.projectionMatrix, false, cameraMatrix);
    gl.uniformMatrix4fv(uniformLocations.modelViewMatrix, false, matrix);

    if (fill) {

      enableAttrib(positionsBuffer, vertexPosition, gl, vertexAttribInfo);
      enableAttrib(fragColorPos, vertexColor, gl, vertextColorAttribInfo);
      gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, vertexCount);
      gl.disableVertexAttribArray(vertexColor);

    }


    if (texture) {

      const _width = canvas.width;
      const _height = canvas.height;

      drawTexture(textureInfo, gl, canvas, enableAttrib, createStaticDrawBuffer, textAttribInfo, vertexCount, textureCoord, uniformLocations.textMatrix, uniformLocations.useText);

    }
  }

  static loadShader(gl, program, type, source) {

    const shader = gl.createShader(type);
    gl.shaderSource(shader, source);
    gl.compileShader(shader);
    gl.attachShader(program, shader);

  }

  static async create(canvas, width, height, zAxis = 6) {
    canvas.width = width;
    canvas.height = height;

    const gl = canvas.getContext("webgl");

    const shaderProgram = gl.createProgram();

    Display.loadShader(gl, shaderProgram, gl.VERTEX_SHADER, VERTEX_SHADER);
    Display.loadShader(gl, shaderProgram, gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER, FRAGMENT_SHADER);

    gl.linkProgram(shaderProgram);


    const programInfo = {
      program: shaderProgram,
      attribLocations: {
        vertexPosition: gl.getAttribLocation(shaderProgram, 'aVertexPosition'),
        vertexColor: gl.getAttribLocation(shaderProgram, 'aVertexColor'),
        textureCoord: gl.getAttribLocation(shaderProgram, 'aTextureCoord'),


      },
      uniformLocations: {
        projectionMatrix: gl.getUniformLocation(shaderProgram, 'uProjectionMatrix'),
        modelViewMatrix: gl.getUniformLocation(shaderProgram, 'uModelViewMatrix'),
        textMatrix: gl.getUniformLocation(shaderProgram, 'uTextMatrix'),
        sampler: gl.getUniformLocation(shaderProgram, 'uSampler'),
        useText: gl.getUniformLocation(shaderProgram, 'aUseText'),
        pointSize: gl.getUniformLocation(shaderProgram, 'uPointSize'),
      },
    };

    gl.useProgram(programInfo.program);

    gl.uniform1f(programInfo.uniformLocations.pointSize, 1.0);

    gl.enable(gl.BLEND);
    gl.blendFunc(gl.ONE, gl.ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

    const textureBuffer = gl.createTexture();

    gl.activeTexture(gl.TEXTURE0);
    gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, textureBuffer);
    gl.uniform1i(programInfo.uniformLocations.uSampler, 0);

    const textureCanvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    textureCanvas.width = 0;
    textureCanvas.height = 0;

    let texture = {
      canvas: textureCanvas,
      buffer: textureBuffer,
      context: textureCanvas.getContext("2d"),
    };

    return new Display(gl, programInfo, zAxis, texture);
  }
}

class Entity extends Rect {

  constructor() {

    super();

    this.velocity = vec2.create();
    this.area = undefined;
    this.mass = 2;

    this.updateFillers = {};
    this.delete = false;
    this.draw = true;
  }

  setup(w, h, ...args) {
    this.area = vec2.fromValues(w, h);
    super.setup(...args);

    return this;
  }

  fill(...args) {
    this.updateFillers.fill = args;
  }

  attachImage(image) {
    super.attachImage(image);
  }

  move(x, y) {

    super.move([x, y, this.coords[2]]);

    return this;

  }

  setSize(w, h) {

    if (typeof w == "object") {
      h = w[1];
      w = w[0];
    }

    const area = this.area;
    const [_w, _h] = area;
    super.scale([w / _w, h / _h, 1]);

    area[0] = w;
    area[1] = h;

    return this;

  }

}

class Engine {
  constructor(time_step, update, render, allowedSkippedFrames) {
    this.accumulated_time = 0;
    this.animation_frame_request = undefined, this.time = undefined, this.time_step = time_step, this.updated = false;
    this.update = update;
    this.render = render;
    this.allowedSkippedFrames = allowedSkippedFrames;
    this.run = this.run.bind(this);
    this.end = false;
  }
  run(time_stamp) {
    const {
      accumulated_time,
      time,
      time_step,
      updated,
      update,
      render,
      allowedSkippedFrames,
      end
    } = this;
    this.accumulated_time += time_stamp - time;
    this.time = time_stamp;
    update(time_stamp);

    render(time_stamp);

    if (end) {
      return;
    }
    this.animation_frame_request = requestAnimationFrame(this.run);
  }
  start() {
    this.accumulated_time = this.time_step;
    this.time = performance.now();
    this.animation_frame_request = requestAnimationFrame(this.run);
  }
  stop() {
    this.end = true;
    cancelAnimationFrame(this.animation_frame_request);
  }
}

const engineMath = {
  randomBetween: function(min, max) {
    return min + Math.random() * (max - min);
  },

};

class Quixotic {

  constructor(display) {

    this.display = display;

    this.engine = undefined;

    this.render = undefined;
    this.update = undefined;
    this.frameRate = undefined;

    this.time = 0;
    this.speed = 1;
    this.world = {

      objects: {},
      objectsCollisionInfo: {},
      objectsArray: [],
      classesInfo: {}

    };

    this.timePassed = 0;

  }

  createEntity(Class, ...args) {
    const display = this.display;
    const {
      rect,
      stroke
    } = display.createRectPos(5, 5);

    let instance = new Entity();

    instance.setup(5, 5, ...display.getRectInfo(0, 0, rect, stroke, "#000"));
    this.world.objectsArray.push(instance);
    return instance;
  }

  createBackground(objects) {
    const buffer = document.createElement("canvas").getContext("2d");

    const bufferRect = this.createEntity();
    const display = this.display;

    let {
      zAxis,
      canvas: {
        width,
        height,
      },
      currentCamera
    } = display;
    const cameraMatrix = currentCamera.matrix;

    zAxis--;
    const halfZ = zAxis / 2;
    let {
      coords: [x, y],
      area: [w, h]
    } = objects[objects.length - 1];

    const worldViewProjection = mat4.create();
    let [bX, bY, lX, lY] = [x + w, y + h, x - w, y - h]; //big x, little x

    for (let i = objects.length - 1; i--;) {
      const object = objects[i];
      const {
        coords: [_x, _y],
        area: [_w, _h]
      } = objects[i];

      if (_x > bX) {
        bX = _x + _w;
      } else if (_x < lX) {
        lX = _x - _w;
      }
      if (_y > bY) {
        bY = _y + _h;
      } else if (_y < lY) {
        lY = _y - _h;
      }

    }

    buffer.canvas.width = width;
    buffer.canvas.height = height;

    for (let i = objects.length; i--;) {
      const {
        coords: [_x, _y],
        area: [_w, _h]
      } = objects[i];
      mat4.multiply(worldViewProjection, this.display.currentCamera.matrix, objects[i].matrix);
      const points = [
        [-_w / 2, -_h / 2, 0],
        [_w / 2, _h / 2, 0],
      ].map(p => {
        const ndc = vec3.transformMat4([], p, worldViewProjection);
        return [
          (ndc[0] * 0.5 + 0.5) * width,
          (ndc[1] * -0.5 + 0.5) * height,
        ];
      });
      const ww = points[1][0] - points[0][0];
      const hh = points[1][1] - points[0][1];

      buffer.strokeStyle = 'red';
      buffer.strokeRect(...points[0], ww, hh);
    }

    bufferRect.move((bX + lX) / 2, (bY + lY) / 2);

    bufferRect.setSize(Math.abs(bX) + Math.abs(lX) - 5, Math.abs(bY) + Math.abs(lY) - 5);

    const texture = display.textureFromImage(buffer.canvas);

    bufferRect.attachImage(texture);

  }

  buildWorld({
    objects,
    classes,
    tileMap
  }) {

    const world = this.world;

    if (Array.isArray(objects)) {
      for (let i = objects.length - 1; i > -1; i--) {
        const object = objects[i];
        const {
          amount,
          position,
        } = object;

        const {
          rangeX,
          rangeY
        } = position;

        let _array = [];

        for (let j = amount; j--;) {
          const instance = this.createEntity();
          instance.move(engineMath.randomBetween(...rangeX), engineMath.randomBetween(...rangeY));

          _array.push(instance);
        }
        world.objects[name] = _array;
        world.objectsArray.push(..._array);
      }
    }
    return;

  }


  setup(game) {

    const {
      style: {
        backgroundColor,
        backgroundImage,
        stroke
      },
      world,
      engine: {
        frameRate,
        update,
        render
      },
      setup
    } = game;
    this.buildWorld(world);
    const {
      display,
      world: {
        objectsArray,
        objects
      }
    } = this;

    this.frameRate = frameRate;
    let lastUpdated = 0;
    this.update = (time) => {
      let deltaTime = time - lastUpdated;
      lastUpdated = time;
      const speed = this.speed;
      this.timePassed += deltaTime * speed;

      update(deltaTime / 1000, this);
    };
    let lastRendered = 0;
    this.render = (timeStamp) => {
      if (backgroundColor) display.clear(backgroundColor);
      const length = objectsArray.length;
      for (let i = length; i--;) {
        const object = objectsArray[length - i - 1];
        if (object.draw) {
          const updateFillers = Object.entries(object.updateFillers);
          const fillersLength = updateFillers.length;
          if (fillersLength) {
            for (let j = fillersLength; j--;) {
              const [func, args] = updateFillers[fillersLength - j - 1];
              display[func + "Rect"](object, ...args);
            }
            object.updateFillers = {};
          }
          display.drawBuffer(object);
        }
      }

      render(display, this);
    };
    setup(this, this.world);
    this.engine = new Engine(this.frameRate, this.update, this.render, 3);
    this.engine.start();
    return game;
  }

  static async create({
    display: {
      canvas,
      width,
      height,
      zAxis
    },
    homeURL
  }) {

    const display = await Display.create(canvas, width, height, zAxis);

    return new Quixotic(display);
  }

}

const fps = document.querySelector("#fps");
const minLength = innerWidth > innerHeight ? innerHeight : innerWidth;
const game = {

  create: {

    display: {

      canvas: document.querySelector("#canvas"),
      zAxis: 90,
      width: minLength,
      height: minLength,

    },

    homeURL: "/src"
  },

  style: {
    backgroundColor: "#111122"
  },

  world: {
    objects: [{
      name: "trees",

      array: true,
      amount: 5,
      position: {
        type: "random",
        rangeX: [-37.5, 37.5],
        rangeY: [-37.5, 37.5]

      }
    }]
  },

  engine: {

    frameRate: 1000 / 30,

    update: function(deltaTime, engine) {
      fps.innerText = 1 / deltaTime;
    },

    render: function(display) {}
  },

  setup: function(engine, {
    objectsArray
  }) {

    objectsArray.forEach(tree => {
      tree.fill("#00ff00")
    })
    engine.createBackground(objectsArray);
  }

};



Quixotic.create(game.create)
  .then(engine => {

    engine.setup(game);
  });
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  background-color: #111c31;
  overflow: hidden;
  align-items: space-around;
  display: grid;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

#canvas {
  background-color: #152646;
  /* justify-self: center; */
}

#fps {
  position: fixed;
  color: white;
  right: 0;
}

canvas {
  position: fixed
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gl-matrix/2.8.1/gl-matrix-min.js"></script>

<canvas id="canvas" width="300" height="300"></canvas>
<p id="fps"></p>
```

Comment: *"draw all bunch of rectangles in a 3d world on a 2d world,"* - this is unclear, because the perspective projection matrix is set in either cases. Why do you try to transform some  geometry by the perspective projection matrix `worldViewProjection`, when this is done in the vertex shader, too?

Answer (score 0):

You compute affine coordinates to a perspective projection. For this the corners of the rectangles are transformed by the view matrix and projection matrix. That seems to work fine, but you missed to change the projection and view matrix when the red rectangles are drawn. Hence the vertex coordinates are transformed twice by the projection and view matrix. First when the affine coordinates are computed and 2nd time in the vertex shader.

When you draw the red rectangles then you have to set an orthographic projection matrix that matches the unit of the red rectangles, and view matrix has to be the [Identity matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_matrix).
The red rectangles are drawn to a plane in a coordinated system where an area with the size of 5x5 is mapped on the viewport. The center is at (0, 0). Hence the orthographic projection matrix is

```non
[2/5,0,0,0, 0,2/5,0,0, 0,0,1,0, 0,0,0,1]
```

Change the view matrix and projection matrix after the green objects have been drawn:

```js
gl.uniformMatrix4fv(uniformLocations.projectionMatrix, false, cameraMatrix);
gl.uniformMatrix4fv(uniformLocations.modelViewMatrix, false, matrix);

if (fill) {

    enableAttrib(positionsBuffer, vertexPosition, gl, vertexAttribInfo);
    enableAttrib(fragColorPos, vertexColor, gl, vertextColorAttribInfo);
    gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, vertexCount);
    gl.disableVertexAttribArray(vertexColor);
}

const ortho_mat = [2/5,0,0,0, 0,2/5,0,0, 0,0,1,0, 0,0,0,1];
const identity_mat = [1,0,0,0, 0,1,0,0, 0,0,1,0, 0,0,0,1];
gl.uniformMatrix4fv(uniformLocations.projectionMatrix, false, ortho_mat);
gl.uniformMatrix4fv(uniformLocations.modelViewMatrix, false, identity_mat);

// [...]
```

See the example:

```js
const FRAGMENT_SHADER = ` precision highp float; varying highp vec2 vTextureCoord; varying lowp vec4 vColor; uniform sampler2D uSampler; uniform bool aUseText; void main(void) { if( aUseText ){ gl_FragColor = texture2D(uSampler, vTextureCoord); } else { gl_FragColor = vColor; } } `;
const VERTEX_SHADER = ` attribute vec4 aVertexPosition; attribute vec4 aVertexColor; attribute vec2 aTextureCoord; uniform mat4 uModelViewMatrix; uniform mat4 uProjectionMatrix; uniform mat3 uTextMatrix; uniform float uPointSize; varying lowp vec4 vColor; varying highp vec2 vTextureCoord; void main(void) { gl_PointSize = uPointSize; gl_Position = uProjectionMatrix * uModelViewMatrix * aVertexPosition; vColor = aVertexColor; vTextureCoord = (vec3(aTextureCoord, 1)*uTextMatrix).xy; } `;

function onResize(element, callback) {
  let elementHeight = element.height,
    elementWidth = element.width;

  setInterval(function() {
    if (element.height !== elementHeight || element.width !== elementWidth) {
      elementHeight = element.height;
      elementWidth = element.width;
      callback();
    }
  }, 16);
}


mat4.moveToVec3 = function(out, v) {
  out[12] = v[0];
  out[13] = v[1];
  out[14] = v[2];
};

class WebglEntity {
  constructor() {
    this.matrix = mat4.create();
    this.coords = vec3.create();
  }
  translate(newCoords) {
    const {
      matrix,
      coords
    } = this;
    mat4.translate(matrix, matrix, newCoords);
    vec3.copy(coords, [matrix[12], matrix[13], matrix[14]]);

    return this;
  }
  move(newCoords) {
    const {
      matrix,
      coords
    } = this;
    vec3.copy(coords, newCoords);
    mat4.moveToVec3(matrix, coords);

    return this;
  }
}

class Texture {

  constructor() {

    this.matrix = mat3.create();

    this.image = undefined;
    this.width = undefined;
    this.height = undefined;
    this.rotation = 0;
    this.y = 0;
    this.x = 0;

    let onload = function() {};

    Object.defineProperty(this, "onload", {
      get() {
        return onload;
      },

      set(value) {

        if (this.loaded) {
          value();
        } else {
          onload = value;
        }
      }
    });

    this.loaded = false;
  }

  setup(image, y, width, height, matrix, rotation) {

    this.image = image;
    this.y = y;
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
    this.rotation = 0;
    this.x = 0;

    if (matrix) {
      this.matrix = matrix;
      if (rotation) {
        this.rotation = rotation;

      }
    }

    this.loaded = true;
  }

  static from(texture) {

    const newTexture = new Texture();

    const {
      image,
      y,
      width,
      height,
      matrix,
      rotation
    } = texture;

    newTexture.setup(image, y, width, height, mat3.clone(matrix), rotation);

    return newTexture;
  }

  scale(w, h) {

    const matrix = this.matrix;

    mat3.scale(matrix, matrix, [w, h]);

  }

  rotate(rad) {

    const matrix = this.matrix;
    this.rotation = (this.rotation + rad) % (Math.PI * 2);

    mat3.rotate(matrix, matrix, rad);

  }
}
class Camera extends WebglEntity {
  constructor(fieldOfView, aspect, zNear, zFar) {
    super();

    this.projection = mat4.perspective(mat4.create(), fieldOfView, aspect, zNear, zFar);

  }
  lookAt(lookAt) {
    const {
      matrix,
      projection,
      coords
    } = this;
    mat4.lookAt(matrix, coords, lookAt, [0, 1, 0]);
    mat4.multiply(matrix, projection, matrix);
    return this;
  }
}
class Rect extends WebglEntity {

  constructor() {

    super();

    this.positionsBuffer = undefined;
    this.fragColorPos = undefined;
    this.strokeColorPos = undefined;
    this.strokePositionBuffer = undefined;
    this.vertexAttribInfo = undefined;
    this.vertextColorAttribInfo = undefined;
    this.vertexCount = undefined;
    this.textureInfo = undefined;
    this.strokeSize = 1;
    this.fillers = {
      fill: false,
      texture: false,
      stroke: false
    };


  }

  setup(matrix, positionsBuffer, strokePositionBuffer, vertexAttribInfo, vertextColorAttribInfo, vertexCount) {

    this.matrix = matrix;

    this.positionsBuffer = positionsBuffer;
    this.strokePositionBuffer = strokePositionBuffer;

    this.vertexAttribInfo = vertexAttribInfo;
    this.vertextColorAttribInfo = vertextColorAttribInfo;

    this.vertexCount = vertexCount;

    return this;
  }

  scale(scale) {

    const matrix = this.matrix;

    mat4.scale(matrix, matrix, scale);

    return this;

  }

  attachImage(newTexture) {
    this.fillers.texture = true;

    if (this.multiTextures) {
      this.textureInfo.push(newTexture);
      return;
    }

    this.textureInfo = newTexture;
    this.fillers.TRIANGLE_STRIP = true;

    return this;

  }

}

class Display {

  constructor(gl, programInfo, zAxis, texture) {
    this.gl = gl;
    this.programInfo = programInfo;

    this.canvas = gl.canvas;

    this.currentCamera = new Camera(45 * Math.PI / 180, gl.canvas.width / gl.canvas.height, 0.1, 100.0);

    this.currentCamera.translate([0, 0, zAxis]);

    this.currentCamera.lookAt([0, 0, 0]);

    this.zAxis = zAxis;
    this.drawZAxis = 0;

    texture.textAttribInfo = {
      numComponents: 2,
      type: gl.FLOAT,
      normalize: false,
      stride: 0,
      offset: 0
    };

    this.texture = texture;
    this.spriteSheets = [];

    const context = texture.context;
    const canvas = texture.canvas;

    this.images = {}; /*all the images with their src as their key*/

    onResize(texture.canvas, () => {

      const images = Object.values(this.images);
      for (let i = images.length; i--;) {

        const {
          image,
          y
        } = images[i];

        context.drawImage(image, 0, y);
      }

      const internalFormat = gl.RGBA;

      gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, internalFormat, internalFormat, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, canvas);

      gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_S, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
      gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_T, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
      gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
      gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);

    });

  }


  setSize(width, height) {

    const canvas = this.gl.canvas;

    canvas.width = width;
    canvas.height = height;

  }

  clear(color) {

    const gl = this.gl;

    gl.clearColor(0.1, 0.1, 0.3, 1);

    gl.clearDepth(1.0);
    gl.enable(gl.DEPTH_TEST);
    gl.depthFunc(gl.LEQUAL);

    gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);


  }
  fillRect(rect, color) {
    const {
      createStaticDrawBuffer,
      gl,
      parseColor
    } = this;

    rect.fillers.fill = true;

    if (color) {
      rect.fragColorPos = createStaticDrawBuffer(gl, [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1]);

    }
  }
  textureFromImage(image, texture) {

    const {
      images,
      texture: {
        canvas
      }
    } = this;

    texture = texture ? texture : new Texture();

    const {
      width,
      height
    } = image;

    const y = canvas.height;

    if (canvas.width < width) {

      canvas.width = width;

    }

    texture.setup(image, y, width, height, 0);

    canvas.height += height;

    images[images.length] = texture;

    return texture;

  }

  createRectPos(w, h) {

    const rect = [w / 2, h / 2, -w / 2, h / 2, w / 2, -h / 2, -w / 2, -h / 2];


    return {
      rect,
      stroke: undefined
    };
  }

  getRectInfo(x, y, rect, stroke) {

    return this.createSquareBuffer(rect, stroke, [x, y, this.drawZAxis]);
  }

  createStaticDrawBuffer(gl, data) {

    const buffer = gl.createBuffer();
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer);
    gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(data), gl.STATIC_DRAW);

    return buffer;
  }

  createSquareBuffer(positions, strokePosition, coords) {
    const {
      gl,
      createStaticDrawBuffer
    } = this;

    const positionsBuffer = createStaticDrawBuffer(gl, positions);
    const strokePositionBuffer = createStaticDrawBuffer(gl, strokePosition);
    const modelViewMatrix = mat4.create();

    mat4.translate(modelViewMatrix, modelViewMatrix, coords);

    return [modelViewMatrix, positionsBuffer, strokePositionBuffer, this.createAttribInfo(2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0), this.createAttribInfo(4, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0), positions.length / 2];
  }

  createAttribInfo(numComponents, type, normalize, stride, offset) {

    return {
      numComponents,
      type,
      normalize,
      stride,
      offset
    };
  }

  enableAttrib(buffer, attrib, gl, {
    numComponents,
    type,
    normalize,
    stride,
    offset
  }) {

    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer);
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(attrib, numComponents, type, normalize, stride, offset);
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray(attrib);

  }

   drawTexture(texture, gl, canvas, enableAttrib, createStaticDrawBuffer, textAttribInfo, vertexCount, textureCoord, textMatrix, useText) {

    const _width = canvas.width;
    const _height = canvas.height;

    const {
      x,
      y,
      width,
      height,
      matrix
    } = texture;

    const realX = x / _width;
    const realWidth = realX + width / _width;
    const realHeight = y / _height;
    const realY = (y + height) / _height;

    const fragTextPos = createStaticDrawBuffer(gl, [realWidth, realHeight, realX, realHeight, realWidth, realY, realX, realY, ]);

    gl.uniformMatrix3fv(textMatrix, false, matrix);
    enableAttrib(fragTextPos, textureCoord, gl, textAttribInfo);
    gl.uniform1f(useText, true);
    gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, vertexCount);

    gl.uniform1f(useText, false);
    gl.disableVertexAttribArray(textureCoord);
  }

  drawBuffer(buffer) {

    const {
      gl,
      drawTexture,
      enableAttrib,
      createStaticDrawBuffer,
      currentCamera,
      texture: {
        context,
        canvas,
        textAttribInfo
      },
      programInfo: {
        uniformLocations,
        program,
        attribLocations: {
          vertexPosition,
          vertexColor,
          textureCoord
        }
      }
    } = this;

    const cameraMatrix = currentCamera.matrix;

    const {
      positionsBuffer,
      fragColorPos,
      strokeColorPos,
      strokePositionBuffer,
      matrix,
      vertexAttribInfo,
      vertextColorAttribInfo,
      vertexCount,
      fragTextPos,
      fillers: {
        fill,
        stroke,
        texture
      },
      strokeSize,
      textureInfo,
      multiTextures
    } = buffer;

    gl.uniformMatrix4fv(uniformLocations.projectionMatrix, false, cameraMatrix);
    gl.uniformMatrix4fv(uniformLocations.modelViewMatrix, false, matrix);

    if (fill) {

      enableAttrib(positionsBuffer, vertexPosition, gl, vertexAttribInfo);
      enableAttrib(fragColorPos, vertexColor, gl, vertextColorAttribInfo);
      gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, vertexCount);
      gl.disableVertexAttribArray(vertexColor);

    }

    const ortho_mat = [2/5,0,0,0, 0,2/5,0,0, 0,0,1,0, 0,0,0,1];
    const identity_mat = [1,0,0,0, 0,1,0,0, 0,0,1,0, 0,0,0,1];
    gl.uniformMatrix4fv(uniformLocations.projectionMatrix, false, ortho_mat);
    gl.uniformMatrix4fv(uniformLocations.modelViewMatrix, false, identity_mat);


    if (texture) {

      const _width = canvas.width;
      const _height = canvas.height;

      drawTexture(textureInfo, gl, canvas, enableAttrib, createStaticDrawBuffer, textAttribInfo, vertexCount, textureCoord, uniformLocations.textMatrix, uniformLocations.useText);

    }
  }

  static loadShader(gl, program, type, source) {

    const shader = gl.createShader(type);
    gl.shaderSource(shader, source);
    gl.compileShader(shader);
    gl.attachShader(program, shader);

  }

  static async create(canvas, width, height, zAxis = 6) {
    canvas.width = width;
    canvas.height = height;

    const gl = canvas.getContext("webgl");

    const shaderProgram = gl.createProgram();

    Display.loadShader(gl, shaderProgram, gl.VERTEX_SHADER, VERTEX_SHADER);
    Display.loadShader(gl, shaderProgram, gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER, FRAGMENT_SHADER);

    gl.linkProgram(shaderProgram);


    const programInfo = {
      program: shaderProgram,
      attribLocations: {
        vertexPosition: gl.getAttribLocation(shaderProgram, 'aVertexPosition'),
        vertexColor: gl.getAttribLocation(shaderProgram, 'aVertexColor'),
        textureCoord: gl.getAttribLocation(shaderProgram, 'aTextureCoord'),


      },
      uniformLocations: {
        projectionMatrix: gl.getUniformLocation(shaderProgram, 'uProjectionMatrix'),
        modelViewMatrix: gl.getUniformLocation(shaderProgram, 'uModelViewMatrix'),
        textMatrix: gl.getUniformLocation(shaderProgram, 'uTextMatrix'),
        sampler: gl.getUniformLocation(shaderProgram, 'uSampler'),
        useText: gl.getUniformLocation(shaderProgram, 'aUseText'),
        pointSize: gl.getUniformLocation(shaderProgram, 'uPointSize'),
      },
    };

    gl.useProgram(programInfo.program);

    gl.uniform1f(programInfo.uniformLocations.pointSize, 1.0);

    gl.enable(gl.BLEND);
    gl.blendFunc(gl.ONE, gl.ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

    const textureBuffer = gl.createTexture();

    gl.activeTexture(gl.TEXTURE0);
    gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, textureBuffer);
    gl.uniform1i(programInfo.uniformLocations.uSampler, 0);

    const textureCanvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    textureCanvas.width = 0;
    textureCanvas.height = 0;

    let texture = {
      canvas: textureCanvas,
      buffer: textureBuffer,
      context: textureCanvas.getContext("2d"),
    };

    return new Display(gl, programInfo, zAxis, texture);
  }
}

class Entity extends Rect {

  constructor() {

    super();

    this.velocity = vec2.create();
    this.area = undefined;
    this.mass = 2;

    this.updateFillers = {};
    this.delete = false;
    this.draw = true;
  }

  setup(w, h, ...args) {
    this.area = vec2.fromValues(w, h);
    super.setup(...args);

    return this;
  }

  fill(...args) {
    this.updateFillers.fill = args;
  }

  attachImage(image) {
    super.attachImage(image);
  }

  move(x, y) {

    super.move([x, y, this.coords[2]]);

    return this;

  }

  setSize(w, h) {

    if (typeof w == "object") {
      h = w[1];
      w = w[0];
    }

    const area = this.area;
    const [_w, _h] = area;
    super.scale([w / _w, h / _h, 1]);

    area[0] = w;
    area[1] = h;

    return this;

  }

}

class Engine {
  constructor(time_step, update, render, allowedSkippedFrames) {
    this.accumulated_time = 0;
    this.animation_frame_request = undefined, this.time = undefined, this.time_step = time_step, this.updated = false;
    this.update = update;
    this.render = render;
    this.allowedSkippedFrames = allowedSkippedFrames;
    this.run = this.run.bind(this);
    this.end = false;
  }
  run(time_stamp) {
    const {
      accumulated_time,
      time,
      time_step,
      updated,
      update,
      render,
      allowedSkippedFrames,
      end
    } = this;
    this.accumulated_time += time_stamp - time;
    this.time = time_stamp;
    update(time_stamp);

    render(time_stamp);

    if (end) {
      return;
    }
    this.animation_frame_request = requestAnimationFrame(this.run);
  }
  start() {
    this.accumulated_time = this.time_step;
    this.time = performance.now();
    this.animation_frame_request = requestAnimationFrame(this.run);
  }
  stop() {
    this.end = true;
    cancelAnimationFrame(this.animation_frame_request);
  }
}

const engineMath = {
  randomBetween: function(min, max) {
    return min + Math.random() * (max - min);
  },

};

class Quixotic {

  constructor(display) {

    this.display = display;

    this.engine = undefined;

    this.render = undefined;
    this.update = undefined;
    this.frameRate = undefined;

    this.time = 0;
    this.speed = 1;
    this.world = {

      objects: {},
      objectsCollisionInfo: {},
      objectsArray: [],
      classesInfo: {}

    };

    this.timePassed = 0;

  }

  createEntity(Class, ...args) {
    const display = this.display;
    const {
      rect,
      stroke
    } = display.createRectPos(5, 5);

    let instance = new Entity();

    instance.setup(5, 5, ...display.getRectInfo(0, 0, rect, stroke, "#000"));
    this.world.objectsArray.push(instance);
    return instance;
  }

  createBackground(objects) {
    const buffer = document.createElement("canvas").getContext("2d");

    const bufferRect = this.createEntity();
    const display = this.display;

    let {
      zAxis,
      canvas: {
        width,
        height,
      },
      currentCamera
    } = display;
    const cameraMatrix = currentCamera.matrix;

    zAxis--;
    const halfZ = zAxis / 2;
    let {
      coords: [x, y],
      area: [w, h]
    } = objects[objects.length - 1];

    const worldViewProjection = mat4.create();
    let [bX, bY, lX, lY] = [x + w, y + h, x - w, y - h]; //big x, little x

    for (let i = objects.length - 1; i--;) {
      const object = objects[i];
      const {
        coords: [_x, _y],
        area: [_w, _h]
      } = objects[i];

      if (_x > bX) {
        bX = (_x + _w);
      } else if (_x < lX) {
        lX = _x - _w;
      }
      if (_y > bY) {
        bY = _y + _h;
      } else if (_y < lY) {
        lY = _y - _h;
      }

    }

    buffer.canvas.width = width;
    buffer.canvas.height = height;

    for (let i = objects.length; i--;) {
      const {
        coords: [_x, _y],
        area: [_w, _h]
      } = objects[i];
      mat4.multiply(worldViewProjection, this.display.currentCamera.matrix, objects[i].matrix);
      const points = [
        [-_w / 2, -_h / 2, 0],
        [_w / 2, _h / 2, 0],
      ].map(p => {
        const ndc = vec3.transformMat4([], p, worldViewProjection);
        return [
          (ndc[0] * 0.5 + 0.5) * width,
          (ndc[1] * -0.5 + 0.5) * height,
        ];
      });
      const ww = points[1][0] - points[0][0];
      const hh = points[1][1] - points[0][1];

      buffer.strokeStyle = 'red';
      buffer.strokeRect(...points[0], ww, hh);
    }

    bufferRect.move((bX + lX) / 2, (bY + lY) / 2);

    bufferRect.setSize(Math.abs(bX) + Math.abs(lX) - 5, Math.abs(bY) + Math.abs(lY) - 5);

    const texture = display.textureFromImage(buffer.canvas);

    bufferRect.attachImage(texture);

  }

  buildWorld({
    objects,
    classes,
    tileMap
  }) {

    const world = this.world;

    if (Array.isArray(objects)) {
      for (let i = objects.length - 1; i > -1; i--) {
        const object = objects[i];
        const {
          amount,
          position,
        } = object;

        const {
          rangeX,
          rangeY
        } = position;

        let _array = [];

        for (let j = amount; j--;) {
          const instance = this.createEntity();
          instance.move(engineMath.randomBetween(...rangeX), engineMath.randomBetween(...rangeY));

          _array.push(instance);
        }
        world.objects[name] = _array;
        world.objectsArray.push(..._array);
      }
    }
    return;

  }


  setup(game) {

    const {
      style: {
        backgroundColor,
        backgroundImage,
        stroke
      },
      world,
      engine: {
        frameRate,
        update,
        render
      },
      setup
    } = game;
    this.buildWorld(world);
    const {
      display,
      world: {
        objectsArray,
        objects
      }
    } = this;

    this.frameRate = frameRate;
    let lastUpdated = 0;
    this.update = (time) => {
      let deltaTime = time - lastUpdated;
      lastUpdated = time;
      const speed = this.speed;
      this.timePassed += deltaTime * speed;

      update(deltaTime / 1000, this);
    };
    let lastRendered = 0;
    this.render = (timeStamp) => {
      if (backgroundColor) display.clear(backgroundColor);
      const length = objectsArray.length;
      for (let i = length; i--;) {
        const object = objectsArray[length - i - 1];
        if (object.draw) {
          const updateFillers = Object.entries(object.updateFillers);
          const fillersLength = updateFillers.length;
          if (fillersLength) {
            for (let j = fillersLength; j--;) {
              const [func, args] = updateFillers[fillersLength - j - 1];
              display[func + "Rect"](object, ...args);
            }
            object.updateFillers = {};
          }
          display.drawBuffer(object);
        }
      }

      render(display, this);
    };
    setup(this, this.world);
    this.engine = new Engine(this.frameRate, this.update, this.render, 3);
    this.engine.start();
    return game;
  }

  static async create({
    display: {
      canvas,
      width,
      height,
      zAxis
    },
    homeURL
  }) {

    const display = await Display.create(canvas, width, height, zAxis);

    return new Quixotic(display);
  }

}

const fps = document.querySelector("#fps");
const minLength = innerWidth > innerHeight ? innerHeight : innerWidth;
const game = {

  create: {

    display: {

      canvas: document.querySelector("#canvas"),
      zAxis: 90,
      width: minLength,
      height: minLength,

    },

    homeURL: "/src"
  },

  style: {
    backgroundColor: "#111122"
  },

  world: {
    objects: [{
      name: "trees",

      array: true,
      amount: 5,
      position: {
        type: "random",
        rangeX: [-37.5, 37.5],
        rangeY: [-37.5, 37.5]

      }
    }]
  },

  engine: {

    frameRate: 1000 / 30,

    update: function(deltaTime, engine) {
      fps.innerText = 1 / deltaTime;
    },

    render: function(display) {}
  },

  setup: function(engine, {
    objectsArray
  }) {

    objectsArray.forEach(tree => {
      tree.fill("#00ff00")
    })
    engine.createBackground(objectsArray);
  }

};

Quixotic.create(game.create)
  .then(engine => {

    engine.setup(game);
  });
```

```css
* { box-sizing: border-box; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
body { background-color: #111c31; overflow: hidden; align-items: space-around; display: grid; height: 100%; width: 100%; }
#canvas { background-color: #152646; /* justify-self: center; */}
#fps { position: fixed; color: white; right: 0; }
canvas { position: fixed }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gl-matrix/2.8.1/gl-matrix-min.js"></script>
<canvas id="canvas" width="300" height="300"></canvas>
<p id="fps"></p>
```

Comment: I think I see what I did wrong not quite sure though, so basically I just have to move the projection to the center when I draw textures, so  now I have 2 questions, will that work with rectangles at random sizes? and will it affect if I wanted to but a texture on a rectangle with a position of (-400, 20)?